# Using circuitikz, how do I print the gain of a feedback amp as an inner label text rightside up?

Tags: circuitikz

The inner label (t=) for the amp is printed upside down, whereas the normal label (l=) is rightside up.  How do I get the inner label to be rightside up?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) node[adder](sum) {};
\draw (sum.east) to [twoport,>,t={D=1}] ++ (4,0) node[above]{$y(n-1)$};
\draw (-2,0) to (sum.west) node[inputarrow]{};
\draw (sum) ++ (.5,0) node[above right] {$y(n)$};
\node[inputarrow] at (4.5,0) {};
\draw (3.5,0) --(3.5,2);
\draw (0,2) to (sum.north) node[inputarrow,rotate=-90] {};
\draw (3.5,2) to [amp,t= $a$,>] (0,2);
\node[above] at (-2,0) {$x(n)$};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems `\ctikzset{label/align = straight}` does not affect inner labels.  (One might even consider this a bug.)  You can always use `\rotatebox` (included, see graphicx manual).

(Note: the inner label is stored as `/bipoles/twoport/text`.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) node[adder](sum) {};
\draw (sum.east) to [twoport,>,t={D=1}] ++ (4,0) node[above]{$y(n-1)$};
\draw (-2,0) to (sum.west) node[inputarrow]{};
\draw (sum) ++ (.5,0) node[above right] {$y(n)$};
\node[inputarrow] at (4.5,0) {};
\draw (3.5,0) --(3.5,2);
\draw (0,2) to (sum.north) node[inputarrow,rotate=-90] {};
\draw (3.5,2) to [amp,t=\rotatebox{180}{$a$},>] (0,2);
\node[above] at (-2,0) {$x(n)$};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]